# Email content within variable

Tags: php

I am creating a form online and I need the email sent out to contain content from a file.

my headers are setup like this

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

and my content is here

```
$email_message = file_get_contents('http://www.link.co.uk/wp-content/themes/themename/email-content.php');
```

The file contains an email template, the problem i have is that the  template is emailed out in raw format.

Here is my code:

```
$email_message = file_get_contents('http://www.link.co.uk/wp-content/themes/themename/email-content.php');


// create email headers

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";                                   
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here Brad, is that your headers are broken and are being overwritten.

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
```

add the concatenates (dots)

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
```

---

Concatenates are like chain links. If one is missing or there are none, something won't "hold" or gets broken. ;-) so only the last line gets processed and ignores both the MIME and HTML declarations.

`$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". ....`

which is a valid declaration since it holds a valid `From:`, it's just that the Email isn't "formatted" the way you wanted it to be.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! thank you very much. I'm new to PHP and people like you are helping me!

Comment: @BradHouston You're very much welcome Brad, I was glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: In theory I was overwriting the header variable every time I declared its content? adding the concatenates adds to the variable instead of overwriting! perfect!

Comment: @BradHouston Exactly. Concatenates are like chain links. If one is missing or there are none, something won't "hold" or gets broken. ;-) so only `$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` gets processed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specified that your email is in HTML in your $header ?

Here is an example :

```
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Source :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php